# panada.crosstab doesn't create square table when column receives the same values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I have a function to create confusion matrix

```
def disp_conf_mat(y_act, y_pred, conf_mat_name):
data = {'y_Actual':    y_act,
    'y_Predicted': y_pred
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['y_Actual','y_Predicted'])
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(df['y_Actual'], df['y_Predicted'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])
sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
plt.savefig(conf_mat_name)
plt.close()
```

but if actual values are [0,1,2,3] and predicted are all zeros [0,0,0,0], the confusion_matrix won't be a square 4x4 and instead is just a 4x1.

```
Predicted  0
Actual      
0          1
1          1
2          1
3          1
```

how can I fill the other columns that don't get any predicted values? (e.g. here column 1,2 and 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected, if need all possible values add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix.reindex(confusion_matrix.index, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```